# Touch-friendly nested checkboxes/drilldown

Tags: dropdown, checkboxes, drop-down-list

I'm designing a widget to select one or multiple regions. Regions can be nested within countries and 'main' regions, like this:

```
France
    - Central France
        - Paris
        - Bourgogne
    - Southern France
        - Dordogne
        - Aquitaine
The Netherlands
    - Zeeland
```

... etc.

Selection of a country or higher-level region checks every lower region, while a higher region gets (semi)checked when (all) lower regions are. Behaviour like this seems pretty standard in checkbox-trees I've seen so far.

The way I'm presenting these options now poses some problems. As there are many sub regions contained within a country, I've collapsed these lists by default. However, clicking a country-name is now ambiguous: does it select the region, or open the list?

So far, I've played with these variations:

- A dropdown arrow which would open the collapsed list, while clicking
  the name or checkbox triggers selection;
- A larger checkbox, where
  clicking the name would open/collapse the underlying list;
- Opening the list when an option is hovered - not workable for touch screens;

I'm presenting as a list that 'drops down', instead of 'flies out', as the latter design wouldn't adapt well for mobile users.

Neither of these options made it abundantly clear that A) a selection can be made or B) a more fine-grained level of control is available.

To summarize:

How can I design a touch friendly region selector with multiple levels that allows multiple selections?

Comment: Would a user often select certain regions that fulfill common criteria except being part of the same country, e.g. “French speaking”, “Metropolitan” or “Atlantic coast”? That would suggest a more complex filter approach would be appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Just an idea]

How about two symbols on each line of your tree.  One for selecting and one for expanding to see children.  You would have to render it manually, maybe as a table with Javascript methods on each image/button to show or hide rows, but once you worked out the basic functionality, it should be fairly easy to render dynamically from the backend.

Answer (score 0):

What about a + next to the country name to open it?  This is a fairly standard paradigm.

Another option would be to make clicking on the country *both* show the country results and open the regions for that country.  This may be the clearest option on a desktop site, where the navigation is generally displayed next to the content.  It wouldn't translate to mobile, though.